# Create a dash graph with multiple dropdown menus

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have the following csv file with 4 different servers and two variables: CPU Usage and Memory Usage.

```html
Server,Time_floor,variable,Value
A,0,CPU Usage,0.4544871794871793
A,0,Memory Usage,0.49389743589743573
A,1,CPU Usage,0.4865365853658536
A,1,Memory Usage,0.4246829268292683
A,2,CPU Usage,0.5371627906976744
A,2,Memory Usage,0.43420930232558136
A,3,CPU Usage,0.5200689655172416
A,3,Memory Usage,0.4970344827586206
B,0,CPU Usage,0.5252307692307693
B,0,Memory Usage,0.4178461538461538
B,1,CPU Usage,0.4401428571428571
B,1,Memory Usage,0.41678571428571426
B,2,CPU Usage,0.5404285714285715
B,2,Memory Usage,0.3617857142857143
B,3,CPU Usage,0.5288999999999999
B,3,Memory Usage,0.5067999999999999
```

What I would like to do is to have a dash app with a dropdown menu which for every server allows me to select which variable I want to plot. The graph would have the time_floor as x axis and the value of the variable on its y axis.

I have a python script which results in the following dash app where the variable dropdown menu depends on the server dropdown:

[image: Dash ouput]
The code is the following:

```
import dash
import pandas as pd
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

df = pd.read_csv('Manual_Log_Filtered.csv')
print(df.columns)

servers = df['Server'].unique()
print(servers)

metrics = df['variable'].unique()
print(metrics)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='servers-radio',
        options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in servers],
        value='A'
    ),

    html.Hr(),

    dcc.RadioItems(id='metrics-radio'),

    html.Hr(),

    html.Div(id='display-selected-values'),
    dcc.Graph(id='indicator-graphic')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('metrics-radio', 'options'),
    [Input('servers-radio', 'value')])
def set_metrics_options(selected_country):
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in metrics]


@app.callback(
    Output('metrics-radio', 'value'),
    [Input('metrics-radio', 'options')])
def set_metrics_value(available_options):
    print(available_options[0]['value'])
    return available_options[0]['value']

@app.callback(
    Output('indicator-graphic', 'figure'),
    [Input('metrics-radio',  'value')])
def update_graph(metrics,
                 year_value):
    dff = df[df['Time_floor'] == year_value]
    print(dff)

    return {
        'data': [dict(
            x=dff[dff['Time_floor'] == year_value],
            y=dff[dff['variable'] == metrics["Value"]],
            mode='markers',
            marker={
                'size': 15,
                'opacity': 0.5,
                'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
            }
        )],
        'layout': dict(
            xaxis={
                'title': year_value
            },
            yaxis={
                'title': metrics
            },
            margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0},
            hovermode='closest'
        )
    }



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

What I would like to see in the graph output is something like this (ignore the red dots): 
[image: Expected ouput]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please, provide a sample of the csv, not a screenshot

Comment: You are right, I have updated my question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing your data in a wrong way.
By using pandas you have to access the data in the following way:

```
x=dff['Time_floor']
y=dff[dff['variable'] == metrics]["Value"]
```

Furthermore if you filter your `Time_floor` variable you will just get one value.
To allow a time chart it would be better to have multiple values.

To apply lines and markers in your figure it is required to set up the mode like this:

```
mode='lines+markers'
```

You should also take a look into your update_graph function.
It looks like the `year_value` variable is missing.